# Word for the product of a challenge

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word (noun) that describes the object created or produced when a challenge is met?

For example, I might challenge a group of people to create either a poem, a painting or a photograph (they choose which). When they have created them and I have collected them all, I would have a group of **__** (fill in the blank). It does not need to be an artistic challenge but could be anything.

Comment: Why not *product* or *creation*, words you yourself use?

Comment: @onomatomaniak  Shouldn't this be an answer rather than a comment? I think _creation_ is perfect, especially since, as you say, the OP uses the root--and uses it thrice. Although _product_ is used as well, it's only once, and I find it a far less appealing word for a work of art.

Answer (score 9):

Well, if it were a contest, I would say "submission(s)" or "entry(-ies)" would be commonly used. I think this could work for a challenge as well. Also, one is said to answer a challenge, so perhaps "answer(s)" would meet your need.

Comment: In the same vein, *offerings* would often be suitable.

Comment: @FumbleFingers +1 for the use of "in the same vein".

Comment: @Terry LiYifeng: I thought it was a bit weird when straight after writing it I saw someone had asked about that very phrase! Maybe I'd seen it without conciously noticing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That may be why we have been so addicted to this site :)

Comment: Thanks to everyone!  I might go with SUBMISSIONS, as that is the best one so far, but it is so generic!  So, on the other hand, I might just make up my own word as well.  We shall see...

Answer (score 4):

Just something that came to my mind, but I don't think they are anywhere near nicely fitting your case.

[Work](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/work):  an artistic creation, such as a painting, sculpture, or literary or musical composition; a work of art.

There seems no challenge explicitly emphasized in the definition of work.

[Masterpiece](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masterpiece): a creation that has been given much critical praise, especially one that is considered the greatest work of a person's career or to a work of outstanding creativity, skill or workmanship.

This word is apparently too much for describing your case, nonetheless it was the first word I thought of. By the way, the word "work" happens to be present in the definition of masterpiece above.

Answer (score 3):

In project management we'd call it a deliverable.  However this doesn't sit comfortably with "challenge".  I think something more ambitious like "achievement" maybe.

Answer (score 2):

Did you stop and think that your use of the word *challenge* is more or less synonymous with *contest?*

The only difference I can see is that contests have winners, runner-ups, and record the order in which the competitors finish, but challenges have those who pass or fail as opposed to a winner, runner-up, etc.

Merriam-Webster defines a *challenge* as "To confront or defy boldly."  Synonymous with *dare*

Are you essentially daring these people to create something?

If so, then you can just call it whatever you want.  Acts of creation. Poems. Arts.  Submissions. Call it anything you want.  But if it is a contest, you can then use the words with competition connotations with a little more tenacity.

Hope this helps, man.